# Euro sign (€) not rendered in PDF export, via jasper Reports

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a query regarding the euro sign (€) used in PDF Export I am unable to see the sign there all I can see is that instead of Euro sign i get a [] .

I have tried several ways, by creating a font and supplying the PDF encoding as CP1252 (Western European ANSI aka WinAnsi)

Also added the Jar of the font in the classpath but no luck.

Also I have added two report properties.

net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding   - as - Cp1250

net.sf.jasperreports.export.character.encoding - as- ISO-8859-15

I can obtain the correct Euro sign in XLS export, but PDF is still not producing. Can anyone please tell me what I am missing out.

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your OP mentions that you are using ISO-8859-15 encoding.  According to [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) page, the encoded value for the Euro sign is `0xA4`.  So you can try to include this escaped value in your XML report, e.g. replace this:

```
€ 100.00
```

with this:

```
&#xA4 100.00
```

Here is a [link to a page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/537106/ireport-xml-and-currency-symbol) in the Jaspersoft community site which discusses your problem in greater length.